# REST Heartbeat for checking service availability

Tags: php, rest, curl, high-availability

I need to implement a heartbeat to check whether my rest server is up and running, I was thinking about a service called "heartbeat" or "echo" together with my other services, that just perform a read from database to response with some value, eg: a version number o whatever, or just saying Hello. And then use curl to send request periodically (eg: every 20 seconds), so far so good. Now I need to develop some scripting for using curl periodically and if there are continuous error response (eg: 3 errors one after the other) I send an alert by email.

I was wondering whether there is any non-comercial (or not-paid) solution "out-of-the-box" to implement the last part (the script sending periodic request and sending alert emails), or if not, how would it the easiest way to get it done.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, and probably should use [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) (or other equivalent tools) to achieve this. Monit can check HTTP services, and take some action (restart service, alert) when request fails